# If $\inf\{b\in\mathbb{R}\mid\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-ax_n-by_n}<+\infty\}=1-a$ for all $a\in [0,1]$, does this equality hold for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory, exponential-sums

Let $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n=1}^{+\infty},\left\{y_n\right\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}\subset [0,+\infty)$ be two sequences of non-negative real numbers. Suppose there exist $\lambda\ge 1, c\ge 0$ such that $\frac{1}{\lambda}x_n-c\leq y_n\leq \lambda x_n+c$, and $\inf\left\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n}<+\infty\right\}=\inf\left\{b\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-by_n}<+\infty\right\}=1.$

Consider a series: $P(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n-by_n}$.

For each $a\in \mathbb{R}$, denote $\varphi(a)=\inf\left\{b\in\mathbb{R}\mid P(a,b)<+\infty\right\}$. It can be shown that $-\infty<\varphi(a)<+\infty$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\varphi(a)=1-a$ for all $a\in [0,1]$, can we deduce $\varphi(a)=1-a$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In your first displayed formula RHS is missing.

Comment: The question in the title is not the same as that in the body of your post. So, which is it? (There should be only one question in one post.)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The right hand side of the first displayed formula is not missing, as you'll see if you look at the code. Nor is the formula "displayed". What I see looks like this:
$
\begin{align}
& \inf\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n}<+\infty\}={}\,\,\,. \\ & \inf\{b\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-by_n}<+\infty\}=1
\end{align}
$
To me that looked as if the right-hand side of the first line is missing. But what really happened is that after $\text{“}{=1}\text{”},$ after the dollar sign, a period appeared. And that period appears to be on$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$first line within a math display. But it is nothing of the sort. Inside the MathJax code, after the first $\text{“}{=}\text{”},$ the next thing is $\inf.$ In other words, you should have seen this: $ \inf\left\{a\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n}<+\infty\right\}=\inf\left\{b\in \mathbb{R}\mid \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-by_n}<+\infty\right\}=1. $

Comment: That is one of many reasons why sentence ending punctuation in MathJax, unlike in LaTeX, should be inside the dollar signs.

Comment: . . . and when I alter my window geometry, the problem goes away.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title and typing. I am not so familiar with this platform and was intended to consult about the question in the body part. @IosifPinelis provides a nice counterexample, thanks a lot!

Comment: @YCSu : Thank you for the clarification. Can you now edit the title of your post correspondingly? Also, if you are satisfied with one of the answers here, these [guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) can now be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\od{\text{odd}}\newcommand\ev{\text{even}}$No. A counterexample is given by
$$x_n=\ln n,\quad y_n=(2+(-1)^n)\ln n.$$

Then all your conditions hold, but $\varphi(a)=(1-a)/3>1-a$ for $a>1$.

---

Indeed,
$$P(a,b)=S_\od+S_\ev,$$
where
$$S_\od:=\sum_{n\ \od}\frac1{n^{a+b}},\quad 
S_\ev:=\sum_{n\ \ev}\frac1{n^{a+3b}}.$$
So,
\begin{align}
P(a,b)<\infty&\iff S_\od<\infty\ \&\ S_\ev<\infty \\ 
&\iff a+b>1\ \&\ a+3b>1 \\ 
&\iff b>\max\Big(1-a,\frac{1-a}3\Big).  
\end{align}
So, $\varphi(a)=1-a$ for $a\le1$ and $\varphi(a)=(1-a)/3$ for $a>1$.

It also follows that $P(a,0)<\infty\iff a>1$ and $P(0,b)<\infty\iff b>1$. So, the rest of your conditions hold as well. $\quad\Box$

Comment: does it satisfy $\phi(a)=1-a$ for $a \in [0,1]$ as per OP requirement? - I do believe you are right and the result doesn't hold though as it's a matter of $\limsup x_n/y_n$ essentially and the condition in the OP on $[0,1]$ doesn't seem strong enough to ensure what we need (by generalized Dirichlet series theory we know the formula for $\phi$ and we know also that the result holds for $y_n=x_n$ by the assumptions above)

Comment: @Conrad : Yes, this condition holds as well. I have just added the details.

Comment: excellent- sorry that I didn;t check it myself though as noted I thought a  bit yesterday  on this when posted on MSE and arrived at the conclusion it cannot hold but was too lazy to think of a counterexample

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Any article studying the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}e^{-ax_n-by_n}$?

**A:** This is the grand canonical partitition sum studied in statistical mechanics, in the form
$$Z=\sum_k e^{-\beta E_k+\beta\mu N_k},$$
where the sum is over states labeled $k$ with energy $E_k$ and number of particles $N_k$; the coefficient $\beta=T^{-1}$ is the inverse temperature of the system and $\mu$ is its chemical potential. See for example these [lecture notes,](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/schwartz/files/7-ensembles.pdf) section 6.1.
Knowledge of $Z$ gives you the thermodynamic properties of the system, the average number of particles $\langle N\rangle=\beta^{-1}d\ln Z/d\mu$, the average energy $\langle E\rangle=-d\ln Z/d\beta-\mu\langle N\rangle$, and its entropy $S=T^{-1}\langle E\rangle-(\mu/T)\langle N\rangle +\ln Z$. The partition sum is known exactly for some lattice models (such as the [Ising model](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY525/tsc18.pdf)), and there exists a variety of approximate methods of calculation.

Comment: The posted question was about $\varphi(a)$. What does this grand canonical partitition sum have to do with that?

Comment: I think is it OK to answer the title question, rather than some question appearing later.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : There is clearly a mismatch here between the title and the body of the post. I think that in such cases, if answering before getting a clarification from the OP, one should try to guess the OP's intent as best one can. Doing so, does one not have to assume that the most relevant information and most of the details are contained in the body -- rather than the title -- of the post? In this particular case, the body of the post has nothing possibly to do with "the grand canonical partitition sum".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Now this matter has been [clarified by the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461130/any-article-studying-the-series-sum-n-1-inftye-ax-n-by-n?noredirect=1#comment1196148_461130). So, of course, the actual question was, not in the title, but in the body of the post.